# Python 2.7 not working in Windows Console

Tags: python, python-2.7, windows-console

I recently upgraded from python 2.6 to python 2.7 and everytime I try todo `python setup.py install` I get.

```
'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

It worked fine with 2.6.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That error sounds like the `python` (or `python.exe` in case you are on windows ) binary is not in your PATH.

Comment: `%PATH%` dint have an entry for \Python27\ 
`set path=%path%;C:\python27`

 That fixed my problem.. Thanks

Comment: @SourD - fyi, ActivePython automatically adds to `%PATH%`